# ImageResizer - specify portrait or landscape

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

We want to take a scanned image and determine if it is landscape or portrait, then based on the user's preference of having it rotated to landscape or portrait, rotate it if needed.

i.e. the user wants it in portrait, but its original format was landscape.

How do we determine if it is portrait or landscape and then if required, rotate it 90 degrees.

Trying something like this, but getting stuck on streams not being opened or reset, etc...But more importantly, is this the right/most efficient approach? I don't see any instructions to do this automatically like :`desiredAspectRation=Portrait;` that would do this already in ImageResizer.net, correct?

```
int? imageWidth;
int? imageHeight;

using (var updatedImageFileStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    ImageJob imageJob = new ImageJob(origFileStream, updatedImageFileStream,
        new Instructions(strInstructions)
    );
    imageJob.Build();

    //change to portrait if required
    imageWidth = imageJob.SourceWidth;
    imageHeight = imageJob.SourceHeight;

    if(imageWidth > imageHeight)
    {
        //updatedImageFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        strInstructions = "rotate=90;";
        imageJob = new ImageJob(updatedImageFileStream, updatedImageFileStream,
            new Instructions(strInstructions)
        );
        imageJob.Build();
    }

    updatedImageFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    //upload image to azure
    await azureRepository.UploadAsync(serverRelativePath, updatedImageFileStream, contentType);
    origFileStream.Dispose();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Got it to work using the below. But not sure it's the most efficient.

- Do you need to create a new stream or can `ImageJob` take the same source and destination to overwrite it...I got an error about cannot access a closed stream when trying, so maybe you do need to create a new stream as I did.
- I don't like the duplicate call to upload the image(`await azureRepository.UploadAsync(serverRelativePath, updatedImageFileStream, contentType);`) but I couldn't figure out how to copy the 2nd image stream over the first so I could retain just one call to the `UploadAsync`. I kept getting cannot access closed stream type errors.
- am I missing anything else?

Working code, but efficient?

```
int? imageWidth;
int? imageHeight;

using (var updatedImageFileStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    ImageJob imageJob = new ImageJob(origFileStream, updatedImageFileStream,
        new Instructions(strInstructions)
    );
    imageJob.Build();

    //change to portrait if required - WORKS, uncomment if want to do 100% of time, or this is how to implement based on a parameter of "change to Portrait"
    imageWidth = imageJob.SourceWidth;
    imageHeight = imageJob.SourceHeight;

    if (imageWidth > imageHeight)
    {
        updatedImageFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        strInstructions = "rotate=90;";
        var updatedImageFileStream2 = new MemoryStream();
        imageJob = new ImageJob(updatedImageFileStream, updatedImageFileStream2,
            new Instructions(strInstructions)
        );
        imageJob.Build();

        updatedImageFileStream2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //upload image to azure
        await azureRepository.UploadAsync(serverRelativePath, updatedImageFileStream2, contentType);
        updatedImageFileStream2.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        updatedImageFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //upload image to azure
        await azureRepository.UploadAsync(serverRelativePath, updatedImageFileStream, contentType);
    }

    origFileStream.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of processing the image just to get the dimensions, you could use `Config.Current.CurrentImageBuilder.LoadImage` instead and query the .Width and .Height on the resulting `Bitmap` instance. Remember to dispose it.

For an MUCH faster solution, you could use [Imageflow.NET](https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet), with the `ImageJob.GetImageInfo()` method to get the width/height, and `ImageJob.BuildCommandString(source, dest, "rotate=90")` to perform the rotation. This will also have the benefit of producing much smaller file sizes at improved quality levels.